# Why do two different divs with 100% total width make one go down and not side by side?

Tags: css

Here's what [I'm trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sH8e8.jpg).

And here's the [result I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LPzMG.jpg).

Here's the relevant html

```
  <div class="s2-r1">
    <img src="./Images/information-orientation.jpg" alt="student orientation">
    <div class="r-content">
      <h2>Orientation date</h2>
      <p>Tue 10/11 & Wed 10/12: 8am-3pm</p>
      <a href="3" class="more">Read more</a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

and css

```
.r-content {
    width: 65%;
}

.section2-right img {
    width: 35%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 16px 16px;
}
```

I'm trying to have the text show next to the picture, but it goes down. What am I missing?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: margins are added to the width value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In HTML, by default, everything goes from top to bottom. So in `s2-r1`, even though you have 2 children elements and they would fit side-by-side, they will go from top to bottom.

There are many ways to make them go from side to side, but the best approach heres is to add `display: flex` to the `s2-r1` class. By the way, you wrote `.section2-right img` for the image selector where it should be `.s2-r1 img`.

```css
.s2-r1 {
  background-color: skyblue;
  
  /* that's all you need */
  display: flex;
}

.r-content {
  width: 65%;
}

.s2-r1 .placeholder {
  width: 35%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 16px 16px;
  color: red;
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="s2-r1">
  <div class="placeholder">Placeholder for Image</div>
  <div class="r-content">
    <h2>Orientation date</h2>
    <p>Tue 10/11 & Wed 10/12: 8am-3pm</p>
    <a href="3" class="more">Read more</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: display: flex solved it. Thanks. I didn't understand what you meant the whole .placeholder thing

Comment: Sorry, I meant `img`, I had to just change it to a placeholder div because I didn't have an image to load. Basically you typed `section2-right` instead of `s2-r1`.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are using margin.

That means 35% + margin + 65% = more than 100%.

Answer (score 0):

Because the DIV is a block element which means it will be one row and bush the other siblings down.